# Finding the index path of an array from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios7, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview, nsuserdefaults

I have a UICollectionView that I am using as a filter to allow users to visually select the categories they would like to browse. As they select (or deselect) those categories I am putting those category names into a a mutable array and storing them in NSUserDefaults.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     NSString *selectedCategory = [categoryNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [selectedCategories addObject:selectedCategory];

     NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [userDefaults setObject:selectedCategories forKey:@"selectedCategory"];
     [userDefaults synchronize]; }


- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     NSString *deSelectedCategory = [categoryNames objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
     [selectedCategories removeObject:deSelectedCategory];

     NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [userDefaults setObject:selectedCategories forKey:@"selectedCategory"];
     [userDefaults synchronize]; }
```

When a user returns back to the filters screen I would like to pre-populate those categories that they selected in the UICollectionView again as selected as they enter. I have been able to pull back the data stored in NSUserDefaults using the code below:

```
NSMutableArray *selectedCategories = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedCategory"]mutableCopy];
```

What I am having trouble figuring out is how to use the array I pull back from NSUserDefaults to compare to my categoryNames array (which lists out all the category names as NSStrings and is used to populate the UICollectionView in the cellForItematIndexPath) and find the corresponding indexpath in order to then pre-select the correct UICollectionView cells.

It seems that -indexofObject will be needed but I have been struggling to use it properly.

I am still fairly new to ios programming so any code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you're loading the list of selected category names before any cells are displayed, such as in `viewDidLoad`. In that case, you would just need to add some logic to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to select cells who's category name is in `selectedCategories`. It might look something like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = ...;

    NSString *category = self.categoryNames[indexPath.item];
    if ([self.selectedCategories containsObject:category] && !cell.selected) {
        [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
        // There seems to be a bug in UICollectionView such that the previous
        // statement doesn't trigger the cell's selected view to be displayed.
        // Adding the following statement fixes the issue. Keeping the above
        // statement because it is important when allowsMultipleSelection is NO.
        cell.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying out your code and running a few NSLogs it appears that when I am creating the selectedCategories array from NSUserDefaults in the 'viewDidLoad' everything is working great. But by the time I call it in cellForRowAtIndexPath (using your code example above) the selectedCategories array appears empty. Any thoughts on why that would be?

Comment: There's was typo in my code. `selectedCategories` needs to be a property or instance variable.

Comment: That worked and the selectedCategoies are being passed through and selected programmatically but now there is a weird interface quirk that I can not figure out. When a user re-enters the page the cells being selected with the code shown above do not show up as selected in the interface (currently I have the background change color on selection) until the user selects another category and then that selection as well as all of the categories from the selectedCategories array become selected visually with the background color change. Any ideas on why that may be happening?

Comment: "currently I have the background change color on selection" Please show the code for this.

Comment: The code that I use to highlight the selected cells is in the cellForItemAtIndexPath   `UIView* selectedBGView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    selectedBGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBGView;`

Comment: This appears to be a bug in `UICollectionView`. I tried this scenario with both `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` and only had the issue with the collection view. In any case, I've updated my answer with a workaround.